# Grails One to Many form

Tags: forms, grails, dynamic, grails-orm

I am currently working on a grails project and am trying to create a one to many form. I have been using the tutorial at the link below to get started:

http://omarello.com/2010/08/grails-one-to-many-dynamic-forms/

The solution has a form with two field of data that are static and one dynamic fiwld where the user is allowed to add as many variables as they want and then save them. below you can see all the various files for this functionality:

**Products.Groovy Domain Class**

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.list.LazyList;
import org.apache.commons.collections.FactoryUtils;

/**
 * Products
 * A domain class describes the data object and it's mapping to the database
 */
class Products {

    String productType
    String product

    List vars = new ArrayList()

    //This represents a product belonging to a single department
    static belongsTo = [dept:Depts]
    static hasMany = [ vars:Dynam ]
    static mapping = {
        vars cascade:"all-delete-orphan"
    }

    def getVarsList() {
        return LazyList.decorate(
              vars,
              FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Dynam.class))
    }

    static constraints = {
        productType blank: false
        product blank:false, size: 1..160
    }

}
```

**Dynam.groovy**

```
class Dynam {

    public enum VarType{
        T("Testimonial"),
        D("Dimentions"),
        N("Networking")

        final String value;

        VarType(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        String toString(){
            value;
        }

        String getKey(){
            name()
        }

        static list() {
            [T, D, N]
        }

    }

    static constraints = {
        index(blank:false, min:0)
        data(blank:false)
        type(blank:false, inList:VarType.list(), minSize:1, maxSize:1)
    }

    int index
    String data
    VarType type
    boolean deleted

    static transients = [ 'deleted' ]

    static belongsTo = [ product:Products ]

    def String toString() {
        return "($index) ${data} - ${type.value}"
    }
}
```

**ProductsController.Groovy**

**Creation Function**

```
def createDynProduct(){
        def productsInstance = new Products()
        productsInstance.properties = params
        //This is used in order to create a new User Object for the current User logged in
        def userObjects = springSecurityService.currentUser

        //This passes the 2 models to the view one being Products and the other a User Department
        [productsInstance: productsInstance, dept: userObjects.dept]

    }
```

**Save Function**

```
def save() {

        def productInfo = "dynam"

        def userObjects = springSecurityService.currentUser

        def dept = Depts.findByName(params.dept.name)

        def product = new Products(product:productInfo, productType:params.productType, dept: dept, vars:params.varsList)

        def _toBeRemoved = product.vars.findAll {!it}

        // if there are vars to be removed
        if (_toBeRemoved) {
            product.vars.removeAll(_toBeRemoved)
         }

        //update my indexes
        product.vars.eachWithIndex(){phn, i ->
            if(phn)
                phn.index = i
        }

        //If the the save is not successful do this
        if (!product.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "create", model: [productsInstance: product, dept: userObjects.dept])
            return
        }

        redirect(action: "show", id: product.id)
    }
```

**createDynProduct.gsp**

```
<%@ page import="com.tool.Products" %>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name='layout' content='springSecurityUI'/>
    <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'messages.label', default: 'Products')}" />
    <title><g:message code="default.create.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
</head>

  <body>

        <g:renderErrors bean="${productsInstance}" />


    <g:form action='save' name='ProductForm' >
        <br/>

        <!-- Render the product template (_dynam.gsp) here -->
        <g:render template="dynam" model="['productsInstance':productsInstance]"/>
        <!-- Render the product template (_dynam.gsp) here -->

        <div class="buttons">
          <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
        </div>
      </g:form>

    <!-- Render the var template (_var.gsp) hidden so we can clone it -->
    <g:render template='var' model="['var':null,'i':'_clone','hidden':true]"/>
    <!-- Render the var template (_var.gsp) hidden so we can clone it -->

  </body>
</html>
```

**_dynam.gsp**

```
<div class="dialog">
  <table>
      <tbody>

      <tr class="prop">
            <td valign="top" class="name">
            <label for="productType">Product Type</label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <g:textField name='productType' bean="${productsInstance}" value="${productsInstance.productType}"
                           size='40'/>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="prop">
            <td valign="top" class="name">
            <label for="Vars">Vars</label>
            </td>

            <!-- Render the vars template (_vars.gsp) here -->
            <g:render template="vars" model="['productsInstance':productsInstance]" />
            <!-- Render the vars template (_vars.gsp) here -->

        </tr>

        <tr class="prop">
            <td valign="top" class="name">
            <label for="Department">Department</label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <g:textField name='dept.name' readonly="yes" value="${dept.name}" size='40'/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**_vars.gsp**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var childCount = ${productsInstance?.vars.size()} + 0;

    function addVar(){
      var clone = $("#var_clone").clone()
      var htmlId = 'varsList['+childCount+'].';
      var varInput = clone.find("input[id$=number]");

      clone.find("input[id$=id]")
             .attr('id',htmlId + 'id')
             .attr('name',htmlId + 'id');
      clone.find("input[id$=deleted]")
              .attr('id',htmlId + 'deleted')
              .attr('name',htmlId + 'deleted');
      clone.find("input[id$=new]")
              .attr('id',htmlId + 'new')
              .attr('name',htmlId + 'new')
              .attr('value', 'true');
      varInput.attr('id',htmlId + 'data')
              .attr('name',htmlId + 'data');
      clone.find("select[id$=type]")
              .attr('id',htmlId + 'type')
              .attr('name',htmlId + 'type');

      clone.attr('id', 'var'+childCount);
      $("#childList").append(clone);
      clone.show();
      varInput.focus();
      childCount++;
    }

    //bind click event on delete buttons using jquery live
    $('.del-var').live('click', function() {
        //find the parent div
        var prnt = $(this).parents(".var-div");
        //find the deleted hidden input
        var delInput = prnt.find("input[id$=deleted]");
        //check if this is still not persisted
        var newValue = prnt.find("input[id$=new]").attr('value');
        //if it is new then i can safely remove from dom
        if(newValue == 'true'){
            prnt.remove();
        }else{
            //set the deletedFlag to true
            delInput.attr('value','true');
            //hide the div
            prnt.hide();
        }
    });

</script>

<div id="childList">
    <g:each var="var" in="${productsInstance.vars}" status="i">

        <!-- Render the var template (_var.gsp) here -->
        <g:render template='var' model="['var':var,'i':i,'hidden':false]"/>
        <!-- Render the var template (_var.gsp) here -->

    </g:each>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Add Var" onclick="addVar();" />
```

**_var.gsp**

```
<div id="var${i}" class="var-div" <g:if test="${hidden}">style="display:none;"</g:if>>
    <g:hiddenField name='varsList[${i}].id' value='${var?.id}'/>
    <g:hiddenField name='varsList[${i}].deleted' value='false'/>
    <g:hiddenField name='varsList[${i}].new' value="${var?.id == null?'true':'false'}"/>

    <g:textField name='varsList[${i}].number' value='${var?.data}' />    
    <g:select name="varsList[${i}].type"
        from="${com.tool.Dynam.VarType.values()}"
        optionKey="key"
        optionValue="value"
        value = "${var?.type?.key}"/>

    <span class="del-var">
        <img src="${resource(dir:'images/skin', file:'icon_delete.png')}" 
            style="vertical-align:middle;"/>
    </span>
</div>
```

The solution works in part so you can go to the products page and it loads with the fields and the dynamic fields are added to the view fine and I can enter the data. However when I click save the data for the static fields is persisted but the dynamic vars are not saved to the domain.

I don’t get any errors but I believe it has something to do with the save function line below and the **vars:params.varsList** in particular.

```
def product = new Products(product:productInfo, productType:params.productType, dept: dept, vars:params.varsList)
```

I have checked the varsList data using println and it returns null, can someone please help with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of doing `varsList[${i}].number` etc.. Try `varsList.${i}.number`. Also, I find it much easier to clear the collection and recreate it from the HTML each time. No longer have to worry about IDs and checking if something is missing.. You can't trust the front end.

Comment: I have made the changes stated and even though I don’t get an error and the save appears successful the variables data is not saved. I will grab the actual console output and put it below...

Comment: products.save: [dept.name:Admin, dept:[name:Admin], productType:Testing, varsList[0].id:, varsList[0]:[id:, new:true, data:This is a Test, type:T, deleted:false], create:Create, varsList[0].new:true, varsList[1].new:true, varsList[1]:[new:true, type:D, id:, deleted:false, data:[Width/Height/Length]], varsList[1].type:D, varsList[0].data:This is a Test, varsList[1].id:, varsList[1].deleted:false, varsList[1].data:[Width/Height/Length], varsList[0].type:T, varsList[0].deleted:false, action:save, controller:products]

Comment: varsList isn't the name of your attribute in Products. If you just use `vars` it works?

Comment: See the lookup tables and metadata set forms in http://maflt.org/ibidem for working examples of this technique.